# Binding ViewModel property in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, catel

For an application I need to create a `DataGrid` with a `DataGridTextColumn` which has `MultiBinding`.
The first `Binding` uses a property given in the ItemsSource, the second `Binding` should use a Property from my ViewModel.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Hourly wage" SortMemberPath="HourlyWage">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
            <Binding Path="HourlyWage" />
            <Binding Path="CurrencyUnit" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

In that case `HourlyWage` is a property of the current item. `CurrencyUnit` is a property in my ViewModel.
If I start my application this column is empty. So how do I get it displaying both?

I'm using Catel as my MVVM Framework and MahApps.Metro for my GUI. I can't create a ViewModel in my View as it is handled by Catel.

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot access the view model, you can define the second binding as follows:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}"
         Path="DataContext.CurrencyUnit" />
```

The source of the Binding will be set to the DataGrid instance. The path `DataContext.CurrencyUnit` will refer to the property `YourViewModel.CurrencyUnit`, assuming that your view model holds the items collection for the data grid and the currency unit property.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Binding Source for the second binding to your view model instance.
I used the following View Model:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.items = new List<Item> {
            new Item("13.4"),
            new Item("22.3")};
        }

        public List<Item> Items
        {
            get { return this.items; }
        }

        public string CurrencyUnit
        {
            get { return "$"; }
        }

        private List<Item> items;
    }
}
```

And the Item class as follows:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Item
    {
        public Item(string hWage)
        {
            HourlyWage = hWage;
        }

        public string HourlyWage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I used the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hourly wage"
                                    SortMemberPath="HourlyWage">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
                            <Binding Path="HourlyWage" />
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource viewModel}"
                                     Path="CurrencyUnit" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add a ViewModel in my XAML as it would break Catel's functionality. (Generating VM twice)