# Binding Value and Currency to DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I would like to bind currency for text column and if i type the value like "de" it is working and i can see Euro. But if I try to bind it it's sending an error.

Ofc i can bind the currency to whole View, but i have always 2 different currencies to display.

There is code that is not working:

```
Binding="{Binding Income,StringFormat=C,ConverterCulture={Binding CultureFormat}}" />
```

and If i do like this it's working properly:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Saldo" Binding="{Binding Balance,StringFormat=C,ConverterCulture=de}" />
```

I found that the is some solution to use multibinding, but i don't know how in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could to this using a multi binding and a converter:

```
public class CultureConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            decimal balance = System.Convert.ToDecimal(values[0]);
            string c = values[1] as string;

            return balance.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(c));
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:CultureConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Saldo">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                    <Binding Path="Income" />
                    <Binding Path="CultureFormat" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
       ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The example assumes that the `CultureFormat` property returns a string. If it returns a `CultureInfo` you could just cast `values[1]` to this type instead of `string`.

Comment: That's nice. But i still cannot see how to bind values from ViewModel in xaml? Because when i bind like Path="MyValueFromViewModel" It's showing anything

Comment: Hey, your solution it does worked but i just had to change Currency field to <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}"
Path="DataContext.BaseCultureFormat" />
as i found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819168/binding-viewmodel-property-in-datagridtextcolumn

Answer (score 0):

`Binding` is not a dependecy object and its properties are not dependency one. To apply a binding to `Binding.ConverterCulture` the source should be a dependency property and I guess that `CultureFormat` is not.

If you need a variable culture info, you can format your data in the ViewModel using a specific property, something like

```
public string BalanceString
{
    get { return String.Format(CultureFormat, "C", Balance); }
}
```

and then use this new property for binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Saldo" Binding="{Binding BalanceString, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: For now i'm doing things like this to workaround this problem.
But i would like to somehow multibind it, because than i 5 fields in this DataGrid with 2 different currencies. and other 2 datagrids with different models. I'm just trying to find better solution for this